# Local database, I need some examples

Tags: c#, database

I'm making an app that will be installed and run on multiple computers, my target is to make an empty local database file that is installed with the app and when user uses the app his database to be filled with the data from  the app . 
can you provide me with the following examples :

1. what do I need to do so my app can connect to its local database
2. how to execute a query with variables from the app for example how would you add to the database the following thing

   ```
   String abc = "ABC";
   String BBB = "Something longer than abc";
   ```

and etc 
Edit :: 
**I am using a "local database" created from " add > new item > Local database" so how would i connect to that ? Sorry for the dumb question .. i have never used databases in .net**

Comment: What type of database are you connecting to?

Comment: I'm thinking of using a local .sdf file

Comment: Updated my answer in response to you spesifying using .sdf (Sql Ce / Sql Compact)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Depending on the needs you could also consider Sql CE.  I'm sure that if you specified the database you're thinking of using, or your requirements if you're usure you would get proper and real examples of connection strings etc.

Edit: Here's code for SqlCe / Sql Compact

```
    public void ConnectListAndSaveSQLCompactExample()
    {
        // Create a connection to the file datafile.sdf in the program folder
        string dbfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName + "\\datafile.sdf";
        SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection("datasource=" + dbfile);

        // Read all rows from the table test_table into a dataset (note, the adapter automatically opens the connection)
        SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from test_table", connection);
        DataSet data = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(data);

        // Add a row to the test_table (assume that table consists of a text column)
        data.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new object[] { "New row added by code" });

        // Save data back to the databasefile
        adapter.Update(data);

        // Close 
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Remember to add a reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe

Comment: just an FYI: SQL CE is SQL Compact is SQL Mobile--CE refers to the slightly out of date version; the latest (2008 generation) is just called SQL Compact whereas SQL CE (Compact Edition) is 2005 generation.

Comment: Both the connection and the dataadapter should be in `using`  blocks.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not seeing anybody suggesting SQL Compact; it's similar to SQLite in that it doesn't require installation and tailors to the low-end database.  It grew out of SQL Mobile and as such has a small footprint and limited feature-set, but if you're familiar with Microsoft's SQL offerings it should have some familiarity.

SQL Express is another option, but be aware that it requires a standalone installation and is a bit beefier than you might need for an applciation's local cache.  That said it's also quite a bit more powerful than SQL Compact or SQLite.

Comment: Here's the SQL Compact site; it's really a pretty solid little Database, especially for how lightweight it is.  http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Seems like you're:

- -Making a C# app that will be installed and run on multiple
  computers
- -That needs a local database (I'm assuming an RDBMS)
- -You need to generate a blank database at installation
- -You then need to be able to connect to the database and populate it when 
  the app runs.

In general, it seems that you need to read up on using a small database engine for applications.  I'd start by checking out [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org), especially if you need multi-OS capability (eg., your C# program will run on Microsoft's .NET Framework and Novell's Mono).  There are C# wrappers for accessing the SQLite database.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this question is about the "Local Database" item template in Visual Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What are you considering as a database?  From what little you've provided in your question, I'd suggest SQLite.

You can get sample code from their site  [Sqlite.NET](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I fully understand what you're asking but Sqlite is a good option for lightweight, locally deployed database persistence. Have a look here:

http://www.sqlite.org/

and here for an ADO.NET provider..

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Answer (score 1):

For 1)

The easiest way to provide this functionality is through [SQL Server Express User Instances](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564(SQL.90).aspx). SQL Server Express is free, so your user does not have to pay additional license for SQL Server, and the User Instance is file-based, which suits your requirement.

For 2)

This is a big topic. You may want to go through some of the [tutorials from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) to get the feeling of how to connect to DB, etc.

Comment: For 1): **No!** It's very rare that you should use Express Edition for a single-user, desktop database.  Instead, use an in-process engine like Sql Server Compact Edition, Sqlite, or even Access.

Comment: My point was, it's the easiest way (may not be the best way). I personally have never used any in-proc DB engine. If those engines are indeed as easy to use (and have the same support level) as SQL Server, then I will stand corrected.

Comment: They are typically easier to deploy (xcopy support for a brand new machine), nearly as easy to develop for (you do have to install an sdk on your dev box, but they'll still follow same data provider model as sql server), and have a _much_ better user experience, since they don't require running sql server in the background even when the app is turned off.