# How to deploy database with an application in C# in visual studio?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, deployment, ssms

I have a desktop application that was developped with **C#** using `Visual Studio 2015`. This application connects to a `SQL Server Management Studio` using **SQL connection string**.

The problem is that I need to deploy this application in other computers; and if I execute it the **SQL server instance** will not be recognized.

Can someone tell me what to do in order for the application to be installed on other computers and make the database deployable?

Thank you,

Comment: use embedded database, like localdb or sqlite.
check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144838/embedding-a-sql-localdb-database-in-c-net)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy application with sql server database on clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956142/how-to-deploy-application-with-sql-server-database-on-clients)